# Selecting content of CEdit control in MFC when clicking the control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How could I select the content of CEdit control just when I click the text of the CEdit.
I could select the content with this code:

```
m_ctrlEdit.SetFocus();
m_ctrlEdit.SetSel(0, -1, FALSE);
```

and i put the code in `ON_EN_SETFOCUS` message handler, but the code doesn't work there.

Comment: Be careful of changing standard Windows behaviour. Users get used to how things work and have an expectation of what will happen on a click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom CEdit control and in the custom class add the handler OnLButtonDown in that put the following code

```
void CMyEdit::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)

    {
        // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
        CEdit::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
        SetSel(0, -1, FALSE);
    }
```

Comment: +1: Note that @Jeeva has allowed the default base class implementation to still take place. That's important.